# KeyError when unittesting Django views/URLs

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to test a URL/view in Django 1.11 and keep getting some errors that appear to be related to URL namespaces. The namespace as defined in the projects main URLs file and the local URL name as defined in the app's URLs file match what I put in the test and all looks fine in the template as well. I've tried a few things from looking at the docs and have no idea what's going on. Would appreciate any help, thank you.

My test for the URL/view:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from .models import Course, Step
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, resolve

...
...

class CourseViewsTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.course = Course.objects.create(
            title="Python Testing",
            description="Sample description"
        )
        self.course2 = Course.objects.create(
            title="New Course",
            description="New course description"
        )
        self.step = Step.objects.create(
            title="Intro to Doctests",
            description="Learn to write tests in your docstrings",
            course=self.course
        )

        # self.client = Client()

    def test_course_list_view(self):
        resp = self.client.get(reverse('courses:list'))
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIn(self.course, resp.context['courses'])
        self.assertIn(self.course2, resp.context['courses'])
```

---

My root `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^courses/', include('courses.urls', namespace="courses")),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name="home"),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

---

My `urls.py` for the "courses" app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.course_list, name="list"),
    url(r'(?P<course_pk>\d+)/(?P<step_pk>\d+)/$', views.step_detail, name="step"),
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.course_detail, name="detail"),
]
```

---

The template being rendered:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}Available Courses{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="cards">
    {% for course in courses %}
    <div class="card">
        <header><a href="{% url 'courses:detail' pk=course.pk %}">{{ course.title }}</a></header>
        <div class="card-copy">
            {{ course.description }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

---

And finally my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 77, in reverse
    extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict[ns]
KeyError: 'course'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/learning_site/courses/tests.py", line 59, in test_course_list_view
    resp = self.client.get(reverse('courses:list'))
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 536, in get
    **extra)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 340, in get
    return self.generic('GET', path, secure=secure, **r)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 416, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 501, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/learning_site/courses/views.py", line 6, in course_list
    return render(request, 'courses/course_list.html', {'courses': courses})
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 107, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 107, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 458, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/Users/Adam/Desktop/Treehouse/DjangoBasics/djangobasics/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87, in reverse
    raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'course' is not a registered namespace
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have course namespace in your template? Maybe try cleaning pyc files ors smth. The visible code looks fine, so there must be an issue with the code we don't see.

Comment: Thanks @mariodev for weighing in. Just tried clearing out all the pyc files and running the tests again, got the same results.

Comment: Oh dear lord. I figured it out. It was an issue with my layout template. Thanks again @mariodev!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly noob problem -- Django was trying to render my `layout.html` template, which I never check because I figured all was well there, and I had one of my url names wrong.